# AssetsSync not use fog_directory in scss files for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm trying use `AssetsSync` to synchronize my assets in my **cloud storage service**. Mostly url are generated correctly,

**FOG_HOST+FOG_DIRECTORY+ASSET_PATH**

```
https://FOG_HOST/app-assets/assets/logo-174f0dbccae5be48248c68fa64f5d22cfa45945cf2c6d41f7ee355e4b47c3865.png
```

But, assets url generated by in scss files, change my **FOG_DIRECTORY** by `minio`, like this:

```
https://FOG_HOST/minio/assets/bg-d3918dac566724ee1921807c7417e4f105582a66c1a94eb77890cf8195f84413.jpg
```

**My style.scss** (vendor/assets/stylesheets)

```
.bg-overlay {
    background: url(assets-path("bg-overlay.png")) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Any body can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem adding this line in my application configuration

```
config.asset_sync.fog_directory = 'app-assets'
```

=)